# Two questions on the Blancmange function.

Tags: fractals, bounded-variation, fractional-calculus

I have two questions about the so-called Blancmange function (which I'll restrict to having domain $[0,1]$). That is, define:

$$ B:[0,1]\to [0,2],\quad B(x):= \sum_{k = 0} 2^{-k}s\big(2^kx\big)$$

where $s: \mathbb R \to [0,1/2]$ is the sawtooth function:

$$s(x) := \min_{n \in \mathbb Z}\,|x-n| = \min ([x],1-[x]).$$

($[x]$ denoting the fractional part of $x$).

$B$ gives an example of a continuous no-where differentiable function. I was just wondering:

**Question 1:** What is known about the (Hausdorff/Box Counting) dimension of the graph of $B$? In particular, does the fact that it is self affine lead to an upper bound on the dimension:

$$X = \{(x,B(x))\,|\,x \in [0,1]\} = T_1(X)\cup T_2(X),$$

where $\displaystyle T_1(x,y) = \left(\frac x2,\frac{x+y}2\right)$ and $\displaystyle T_1(x,y) = \left(1- \frac x2,\frac{x+y}2\right)$?

**Question 2:** Is $B$ of bounded variation?

Plot of $s$:

[image: A graph of the sawtooth function s]

Plot of $B$:

[image: A graph of the blancmange function B]

Comment: According to [Wiki's List of fractals by Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension#Deterministic_fractals), the dimension is $1$, and ["it is of bounded variation on no non-empty open set; it is not even locally Lipschitz"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve#Differentiability).

Comment: Ah okay that seems reasonable enough. In particular, is it so that the upper bound  on $\dim_H$ by virtue of self affinity is in fact 1?